# Issues with creating likes and dislike functions Solidity

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

all so i'm trying to create a like and dislike function insuch a way that each address can only like or dislike a post only and below my implementatin which unfortunately doesn't work as expected assuch would appreciate the help as i'm new to solidity .. Als here's the error i get from my remix console
*"Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.*"
but i know for a fact the function is not supposed to be payable..thanks

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0 ;
contract PostCounter{
struct Counter{
    uint noOfCounters;
    mapping(address => bool) count;
}
Counter[] public counts;
function likeCounter(uint _likesNo)  public {
    Counter storage thisCounter=counts[_likesNo];
    require(thisCounter.count[msg.sender]==false,"you have already like this post");
    thisCounter.count[msg.sender]=true;
    thisCounter.noOfCounters++;
}
function dislikeCounter(uint _likesNo)  public{
    Counter storage thisCounter=counts[_likesNo];
    require(thisCounter.count[msg.sender]==false,"you have already dislike this post");
    thisCounter.count[msg.sender]=true;
    thisCounter.noOfCounters--;
}
```

}

Comment: The counter must refers to a specific post. If this is correct, why did you create a external struct Counter? You can implement the counter about like and dislike inside Post struct

Comment: so my thinking was the mapping in the struct has to keep count of whether an address has liked a post or not and if that's the case then noOfCounters is increase and if the user tries to like the post again then the require statement is triggered.. @Kerry99 is my thinking wrong and is there a better methode u can recommend ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues

- `Counter[] public counts` is an array so `counts[_likesNo]` will revert if `_likesNo` is not a valid index position. Perhaps you wanted it to be a mapping?  `mapping (uint256 => Counter) public counts;`.
- `uint noOfCounters` is an `uint` so it can't be negative. No post will have more dislike than likes. Perhaps you should use a `int` instead.